# how to get details from database for each option mentioned in select list when select the each option in select list

Tags: php, dropdown

doctor select list.Select list name as dn
[image: doctor select list.Select list name as dn]

I want to get doctors information for each doctor separately
[image: I want to get doctors information for each doctor separately]

Comment: Please add a description inside your post and post your code as text.

Comment: Please edit your question, your question isn't clear at all.

Comment: you should add proper code snippet here rather than posting images\

Comment: Post the code not the image of code.

Comment: why is this question still not updated to hold actual code? You've been asked numerous times.

Comment: Flag "The OP has been asked numerous times to post their actual code instead of an image of it and has not updated their question and they are logged in seeing a new question posted this morning, therefore the question should probably be closed as unclear. They are not responsive at all." - *"declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?"* - Whoever was the mod on this, I think you need to take a closer look at what "images of code" are and how this question won't serve.

Comment: This post needs to deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why would you do that, Don't you have these information already in database?

Anyway, this function will return all the content between `<option>` and `</option>` in an array

```
function getContents($str, $startDelimiter, $endDelimiter) {
  $contents = array();
  $startDelimiterLength = strlen($startDelimiter);
  $endDelimiterLength = strlen($endDelimiter);
  $startFrom = $contentStart = $contentEnd = 0;
  while (false !== ($contentStart = strpos($str, $startDelimiter, $startFrom))) {
    $contentStart += $startDelimiterLength;
    $contentEnd = strpos($str, $endDelimiter, $contentStart);
    if (false === $contentEnd) {
      break;
    }
    $contents[] = substr($str, $contentStart, $contentEnd - $contentStart);
    $startFrom = $contentEnd + $endDelimiterLength;
  }

  return $contents;
}
```

usage: `$data = getContents($data , '<option>' , '</option>');`

And now you can call foreach loop to loop over each option.

Comment: Glad that i could help, Please mark the answer if that's helped.