# Add row to table and calculate rows value

Tags: php

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10" style="padding:0px 100px 0px 50px; color:blue;">   
        <form action="#" style="color:blue;" method="POST" >

            <div class="well well-sm" >
                <table border="collapse; border-spacing:5px;" style="background-color:pink;">
                <thead> 
                    <th>Stock ID</th>
                    <th>Medicine Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity Unit</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Selling Price</th>
                    <th>Sold Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                    <th><input type="button" value="+" id="add" class="btn btn-primary"></th>                   
                </thead>
                <tbody class="detail">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="si" name="si"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="mn" name="mn" value="<?php 
                        include_once('classes/class.select.php');
                        $bill = new select();
                        $value = $bill ->billing($_POST['si']);
                            foreach($value as $row){

                            echo    $row["medi_name"];
                            }

                            ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qu" name="qu" value="<?php echo $row["quantity_unit"];?>"></td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="up" name="up" value="<?php echo $row["unit_price"]; ?>"></td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sp" name="sp" value="<?php echo $row["selling_price"];?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="t" name="t" ></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ls" name="ls" ></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Bill" name="savesel"><br></td>          
                </tr>
                </tbody> 
                </table>
            </div>



        </form> 

    </div>
```

This is my table of billing system of medicine. When we give stock Id, the other columns are automatically fill according to relevant stock Id. I want to add some more rows to this table like this. But when I click on bill button on second row, whole row will be disappeared. I also want to calculate whole total price of the end.

```
<script>
function addnew(){
    var n=($('.detail tr').length-0)+1;
    var tr =
    '<tr>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="si" name="si"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="mn" name="mn" value="<?php 
                        include_once('classes/class.select.php');
                        $bill = new select();
                        $value = $bill ->billing($_POST['si']);
                            foreach($value as $row){

                            echo    $row["medi_name"];
                            }

                            ?>"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qu" name="qu" value=["quantity_unit"]></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="up" name="up" value=["unit_price"]></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="sp" name="sp" value=["selling_price"]></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="t" name="t" ></td>'+   
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ls" name="ls" ></td>'+
    '<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Bill" name="savesel"><br></td>'+                       
    '</tr>';
    $('.detail').append(tr);
}

$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        addnew();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: so your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47407546/1415724) still isn't marked as solved, yet you want more help and one that still has an image of code; what are you waiting for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#cloneTable tfoot #addNew").on("click", function() {
    var clonedRow = $('#cloneTable tbody tr:first').clone();
    clonedRow.find('input').val('');
     $('#cloneTable tbody').append(clonedRow) ;
});
```

Comment: You can clone your table tr

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment